# SQL query - counting only the months that met certain condition

Tags: sql

I am having a trouble writing a sql query...basically I have about a million or so rows (cards) with transactions divided into columns - months (12 months).

So each row shows how big transaction did the card do each month.
Now the problem is - I am trying to select only the cards who have met a certain condition only 7 months during the year.

The condition is each month (duration 7 months) they spend more then 5 000 eur.

I just do not know what is the function that would show me the resulst for the 7 months..I have wrote the whole query but for the whole year, now I need to narrow it down just to the 7 months, but do not know how...I have "googled" all over. 
Important - the 7 months doesnt need to be in a row - it can be any month during the year.
Could anybody help me with this?

Tank you, K.

Comment: Please provide proper sample data and expected resuts. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add sample data and table structure and what query you have tried so far so we can help

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Hi,in the rows I have - cards

Comment: select

distinct Card 

sum (case when Date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and tran_amount > '0' then tran_amount else '0' end) as leden,
sum (case when Date between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28' and tran_amount > '0' then tran_amount else '0' end) as unor,
.
.
.
.
.
.
(All 12 months)

from Customer

where Date 2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model to store months in rows, not in columns.

Here is a solution that uses `union all` in a subquery to generate such a structure on the fly, then aggregates and filters with a `having` clause:

```
select card
from (
    select card, month_1 spent from mytable
    union all select card, month_2 from mytable
    -- ... one "union all" statement per column ...
    union all select card, month_12 from mytable
) t
group by card
having sum(case when spent > 5000 then 1 end) = 7
```

This assumes a data structure like:

```
card      -- primary key
month_1   -- amount spent during the 1stmonth
month_2   -- amount spent during the 2nd month
...
month_2   -- amount spent during the 12th month
```

Comment: Should probably be `>= 7`

Comment: @PanChristensen: maybe. This was not that clear in the question. OP stated: *select only the cards who have met a certain condition **only** 7 months*, so I went for `= 7`. It's trivial to adjust the condition to the exact requirement.